# jQuery on mouseover event fires again if child is hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

You can see an example here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/TuH95/5/

When you hover over the li element the event is fired. While still in the li element if you hover over span it will fire again, anyway i can make it fire only once when hovering over span?

Comment: As suggested, mouseenter can be used. But  just modifying the selector to say $(".container span") will work as well, I believe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mouseenter` event that will solve the issue.

```
var i = 0;
$('.container').on('mouseenter', function(){
    i++;
    $('.result').html(i);
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TuH95/7/)**

Comment: According to http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/ ff and chrome do not work with mouseenter or mouseleave (even though it does work in ff for me currently) do you happen to know the compatibility of it?

Comment: @Adam: jQuery replaces the missing functionality, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `mouseenter` event instead:

```
var i = 0;
$('.container').on('mouseenter', function() {
    i++;
    $('.result').html(i);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/TuH95/6/